# Wrap long text when printing into columns

Tags: java, printf, command-line-interface

I print output into columns.

```java
System.out.printf("%-20s %-10s\n", "foo", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");
System.out.printf("%-20s %-10s\n", "bar", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
System.out.printf("%-20s %-10s\n", "boo", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nunc turpis, iaculis ut nisl sit amet, euismod elementum nibh. Cras commodo ex a sollicitudin pulvinar. Phasellus id consectetur libero. Nullam vitae laoreet est, et congue leo.");
```

The result:

```
foo                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
bar                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
boo                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nunc turpis, iaculis ut nisl sit amet, euismod elementum nibh. Cras commodo ex a sollicitudin pulvinar. Phasellus id consectetur libero. Nullam vitae laoreet est, et congue leo.
```

My question is, if I can make the long text wrap, so the output would be something like this:

```
foo                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
bar                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
boo                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                     Nam nunc turpis, iaculis ut nisl sit amet, euismod elementum 
                     nibh. Cras commodo ex a sollicitudin pulvinar. Phasellus id
                     consectetur libero. Nullam vitae laoreet est, et congue leo.
```

When I put `\n` into the long text, it will wrap like this, which is not ideal:

```
foo                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
bar                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
boo                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nam nunc turpis, iaculis ut nisl sit amet, euismod elementum 
nibh. Cras commodo ex a sollicitudin pulvinar. Phasellus id
consectetur libero. Nullam vitae laoreet est, et congue leo.
```

Comment: You are close in you implementation, you just need to add some padding after the \n to push it to the correct position like you did to create the initial columns.

Comment: And is there any elegant way to do it?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with parameterizing prinft. What you want requires some logic like counting padding, line wrapping to prevent splitting words. You can of course make it work on your example by manually padding everything with some number of  `\t` after `\n` but general solution needs some logic to put this together.

Comment: Yea i don't think there is an easy way to do this without some logic to know how much to pad it and not to split words, However, for the implementing of the padding i would use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not perfect, but working reasonably well for me invoked as
`displayWrapped("boo", lorem, "%-20s %-10s%n", 15);`

```
    public static void displayWrapped(String col1Val, String col2Val, String format, int wrapLen) {
        String re = String.format(".{1,%d}(?:[::punc::]|\\b)", wrapLen);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(col2Val);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.printf(format, col1Val, m.group().trim());
            col1Val = "";
        }
    }
```